# Removing newlines and tabs after Regex

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am performing preg_match() on the following HTML code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="phone"> 
        (123) 123-1234
    </div>
```

**Regex Pattern:**

```
/<div class="phone">(?<phone>.*?)<\/div>/s
```

**Result:**

```
[phone] => '
                    (617) 547-6670
      '
```

The extra line and spaces is what I am trying to get rid of. Using `/sm` option does not affect the result. Using `str_replace("\n",'',$string)` got rid of a line, and the spaces infront should be `\t` tabs. I got rid of the annoying stuff with `str_replace("\n\t\t\t\t",'',$string)` but I need a more general solution.

**How can I remove the `\n` and `\t` regardless of how many there are?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you would like, but [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will take care of spaces, tabs, and newlines on each side of the string (but not within the string).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

> **string trim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] )**
>
> This function returns a string with
>   whitespace stripped from the beginning
>   and end of str. Without the second
>   parameter, trim() will strip these
>   characters:
>
> ```
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
> ```

I do realize that this will not handle something like `Hello<space><space><space>World`, but it may be what you're after (outside of the regex).

Comment: `trim()` worked, I tried in on something that required `strip_tag()` to remove extra spacing due to `<p>` tags, and thought `trim()` wouldn't work on this.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the hardest one to find. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to pad the "content" part of the regex with `\s*`, like so:

```
/<div class="phone">\s*(?<phone>.*?)\s*<\/div>/s
```

The first `\s*` consumes as many whitespace characters as it can, stopping when it sees the first character in the phone number.  Then the `.*?` starts consuming characters reluctantly, stopping at the first position where the next part of the regex (`\s*<\/div>`) can match, which is just after the last character in the phone number.

Be aware that the first `\s*` *must* be greedy and the `.*?` in the named group *must* be non-greedy for this to work.  So you if you start feeling the urge to make all quantifiers non-greedy with the `/U` option, resist it.  I mention this because some people use it all their regexes, which I consider a poor practice.  Also, the `/s` (single-line) modifier is necessary but the `/m` (multiline) modifier isn't.

Answer (score 2):

using `\s*`

`\s` is a whitespace character and `*` means any number of including 0

But I think you should look for an html parser, its here probably the better solution.

Comment: Does `\s` handle newlines and tabs as well? I wasn't aware. Is there a difference between this and `\s+`?

Comment: @Wesley Murch `\s` handles also tabs and linebreaks [regular-expressions.info/reference.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). The difference between `+` and `*` is `+` matches at least one, `*` matches additionally 0 characters.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info, I am still very regex-shy after all these years. I need to dedicate a few days to learning them at some point.